# Android Emulator does not view my index.html with PhoneGap

Tags: android, android-emulator, cordova

I am trying to run the sample (or any) application with phonegap in android emulator. I followed all the instructions in the PhoneGap's manual, but instead of the contents of index.html, an ordinary android activity starts. I am using phonegap version 1-2-0 and android emulator with target api 8 (android 2.2). What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is very hard to answer without some more info. I have managed to get phonegap running on the emulator and my phone fairly recently so it works.

Have you tried MDS applaud ? (It's a plugin for eclipse.)

http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start

Comment: You're right, but I don't know which info I need to give here :) I tried the plugin but the result is same.

Comment: I have increased 'ADB connection timeout' to 10000 ms from Preferences->Android->DDMS and it runs index.html now.